# docker-compose can't find file to inject to Postgresql when running a command

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to restore a `.backup` file to a Postgresql database. For that, I use a docker-compose file to launch a postgres docker container:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
   postgresql:
     image: postgres
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "5432:5432"
     environment:
       - POSTGRES_USER:postgres
     # - PGDATA:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/
     volumes:
       - ${PWD}/project/data/MX/bkup/data:/var/lib/postgresql
     command: 
       - pg_restore -U postgres -d postgres /var/lib/postgresql/ph.backup
```

When I run my docker-compose file using the command:

`docker-compose up postgresql`

I get the error:

```sh
(virtual) med@nid:~/projects/project/pkg$ docker-compose up postgresql 
Recreating pkg_postgresql_1 ... 
Recreating pkg_postgresql_1 ... done
Attaching to pkg_postgresql_1
postgresql_1     | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 176: /pg_restore -U postgres -d postgres /var/lib/postgresql/ph.backup: No such file or directory
pkg_postgresql_1 exited with code 127
```

This happens even though the file is inside the volume

```sh
med@nid:~/projects/project/pkg$ docker-compose exec postgresql bash
root@ab7dbe2b0232:/# cd /var/lib/postgresql/
root@ab7dbe2b0232:/var/lib/postgresql# ls -l 
total 1054780
drwx------ 19 postgres postgres       4096 Oct  2 08:51 data
-r--r--r--  1 postgres ssl-cert 1080082803 Sep 27 15:40 ph.backup
```

I tried to use the `-h` argument of `pg_restore` in the docker-compose command:

```
pg_restore -h tcp://`docker-machine ip default`:5432 -U postgres -d postgres /var/lib/postgresql/ph.backup
```

**What works**:
If I comment the command target in the `docker-compose.yml`, launch the docker container and run the command inside it I get to have the data injected!

Is there a fix for this, Meaning, is there a way to make the command work directly from the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 4):

There are two forms of Docker Compose `command:`.  You should move the command up on to the same line

```
command: pg_restore -U postgres -d postgres /var/lib/postgresql/ph.backup
```

The form you have individually spells out each argument (in a YAML list); for example

```
command:
  - /bin/ls
  - -l
  - -r
  - -t
```

(Also consider just installing the PostgreSQL client tools on your host and running this outside of Docker; use `localhost` as the host name and the first number from the database container's `ports:` as the port number.)

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from the form of the `command` configuration. If you inspect the finished postgres container (`docker inspect <container-id>`) the entrypoint and command look like this:

```
"Cmd": [
    "pg_restore -U postgres -d postgres /var/lib/postgresql/ph.backup"
],

"Entrypoint": [
    "docker-entrypoint.sh"
]
```

That practically means that the default entrypoint script [docker-entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh) 
is executed with one argument which is the `pg_restore` command. At line 176 the script execs the passed in arguments (`exec "$@"`). 
The exec command needs a command and a list of arguments

```
exec [command [arguments]]
```

but in this case the command is the full string formed by `pg_restore` and its arguments. This obviously is not a valid file

Now, if you change `command` in `docker-compose.yml` to:

```
command: pg_restore -U postgres -d postgres /var/lib/postgresql/ph.backup
```

inspecting the container shows the following:

```
"Cmd": [
    "pg_restore",
    "-U",
    "postgres",
    "-d",
    "postgres",
    "/var/lib/postgresql/ph.backup"
]
```

that means that `exec` will run `pg_restore` as command passing the rest as arguments and everything works as expected.

In alternative you could override the entrypoint in the docker-compose file to execute the command in a [shell](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

```
entrypoint: /bin/bash -c
command: 
   - pg_restore -U postgres -d postgres /var/lib/postgresql/ph.backup
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this @b0gusb, however, even when I changed the way I wrote the command, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @MohamedNidabdella Could you inspect the container to check if the command really changed? I would also suggest you remove restart: always and stop the containers from restarting using docker update --restart=no $(docker ps -a -q) until you fix the problem